# No projects found when building a solution in memory using Roslyn

Tags: compilation, roslyn, solution

I am trying to compile a solution in memory using the Roslyn compiler. I am using the latest stable Nuget packages (version 2.4.0), the project that is compiling the solution is a .Net 4.6.1 class library.

The problem is that the project graph does not contain any projects.

```
var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionUrl).Result;
var projectGraph = solution.GetProjectDependencyGraph();
var projects = projectGraph.GetTopologicallySortedProjects();
if (!projects.Any())
{
   Console.WriteLine($"{projects.Count()} projects :(");
   return false;
}
```

I might be missing some point. I have created a MVP solution in case you'd like to help me. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Karel

Comment: I forgot to provide the link to the Github repo - https://github.com/kfrajtak/DotIntrospection

Comment: Look in workspace.Diagnostics to see if there were failures during OpenSolutionAsync

Comment: You also need the same redirects that the msbuild.exe.config file has in your app.config file.  Otherwise many msbuild features may fail.

Comment: Thanks, @MattWarren - "Cannot open project 'C:\Work\bitbucket\DotIntrospection\DotIntrospection\DotIntrospection.csproj' because the language 'C#' is not supported." ...

Comment: When it says that C# is not supported, it means it cannot find the C# versions of the workspace and compiler dlls.  Is it possible that you have only installed nugets that have VB?  Or possibly that the dlls are not getting copied to the project's output directory?

Comment: @MattWarren, I have fixed that, but now I am getting `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. `